# Can you prove this number theory conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, conjectures

I think I can prove the following (using a conjecture):

$$ 2n (\sum_{i=2}^n p_i ) \geq p_n(p_n+1)/2 - 6$$

where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime. Can one prove this without any conjecture?

Comment: are $p_i$ primes?

Comment: yes it is as you think

Comment: What is the meaning of proving something *without any conjecture*?

Comment: I assumed a conjecture to be true to arrive at this result and I hope the person who answers the question does not have to assume the validity of a conjecture to prove it.

Comment: What conjecture did you assume?

Comment: Goldbach's Conjecture

Comment: The left side is (asymptotically) $n^3\log n$, the right, $n^2(\log n)^2/2$, so it should be true with room to spare, and should follow from standard estimates.